# jQuery Slider - Next image is split in half behind

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I'd like to create a jQuery slider that shows the next picture behind the current one, only it is split in half. It would pyramid outward. Something like:

[3[2[ 1 ]2]3]

I then need the two halves to come together every X number of seconds as the current pictures goes away...

I feel like it should be pretty simple, but I can't wrap my head around the concept! Going to take a little break and try again, but for the time being if anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? For a start, you could whip up a HTML with 3 images stacked on top of each other maybe?

Comment: They changed their mind on having the images split in half, so I have not followed up on this. I will leave this so that if someone has an answer they can help someone else out. I will check back and check an answer if one does end up getting provided!

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to follow up and say that I never really found a way to do this. Decided against the idea soon after and didn't do much other research. Sorry